# Use of zero to the power of zero

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing, exponentiation

To my understanding, the value of $0^0$ is usually undefined, however sometimes people define it to be equal to either $1$ or $0$, when they need certain formulas to work for practical purposes.
 
My question is, can defining $0^0=0$ or $0^0=1$ be used while proving theorems and why?

Slight clarification: Imagine that some well-known mathematician publishes a proof to one of the millennium problems. However, their proof requires that $0^0=1$. Will such proof be generally accepted, given that there are no other flaws in the proof?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to0^+}0^x=0,\lim_{x\to0^+}x^0=1,\lim_{x\to0^+}x^x=1$.

Comment: In my openion there is actually 3 zeros $0^+$ , $0^-$ and $0$ so if you mean the last one then it shoud be undefined.

Comment: Yes, proofs that only work if $0^0=1$ are accepted. For example, the proof of the binomial theorem assumes that $0^0=1$, and the theorem itself also implies $0^0=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define it to be whatever you want. All you need to do is to say what you defined it to be, and use it consistently and in a way consistent with your choice.

By the way, *usually* $0^0$ is defined as $1$, since this makes consistent use most convenient (in many persons' minds).

To illustrate what I mean, you can say $0^0 = 13$. But if you do this, *then* you cannot compute $0^0 \cdot 0^0 = 0^{0+0} = 0^0$, because $0^0 \cdot 0^0 = 0^{0+0}$ just is not true under this choice.

If instead you choose $0^0 = 1$ then it is true that $0^0 \cdot 0^0 = 0^{0+0}$, which is intuitive and convenient and makes a more reasonable choice than $0^0 = 13$.

---

On the clarified question: **yes,** it is basically a *choice of notation;* it is not really a requirement as such. Whether one accepts the proof or not would also not depend on one's own preferred choice. It is not some 'believe' or anything like that, it's just a convention.

Yet note that  $0^0 = 1$ must not be confused with the assertions like:

> For $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ sequences of positive reals. If $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = 0$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^{b_n} = 1$.

This is just **wrong** in general, and assuming it to be true would invalidate the proof.

Comment: I usually see the justification $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} x\ln(x) = 0 \Rightarrow x^{x} = e^{x\ln(x)} \rightarrow e^{0} = 1$. This doesn't mean that $0^{0}$ must be $1$, but it is the continuous extension of $x^{x}$ which gives it some legitimacy.

Answer (score -1):

Thats tricky but easy to prove that 0th power of 0 equals to one.The image attached herewith the answer contains it's calculation. 
[calculation of zeroth power of zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7XIz.jpg)