# When the input to a polynomial is zero and the final term is a constant, why is the evaluation defined or non-zero?

Tags: polynomials, exponentiation

For example, the polynomial in the function $P(x) = 3x^4-2x^3+x^2+7x+8$ could be written as $3x^4-2x^3+x^2+7x^1+8x^0$, and it should mean the same thing for anything to the unary power is identical to itself and anything to the zeroeth power is equal to the unit quantity (1).

However I’m having difficulty evaluating the second case if the input is zero.  For $P(x) = 3x^4-2x^3+x^2+7x+8$ = 8, but $x^0 = 0^0 = $ undefined in $3x^4-2x^3+x^2+7x^1+8x^0$.

So how is the first one defined or non-zero if the more explicit form of the polynomial is not?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898330/use-of-zero-to-the-power-of-zero

Comment: In the context of polynomials or power series, the convention $0^0 = 1$ is always used, for this very reason.

Comment: A constant term is a constant. You are making the evaluation overly complicated.

Comment: When when you said the polynomial "could be written" with final term $8x^0$, That "could be written" is only true under the convention $0^0 = 1$. If you insist that $0^0$ must be undefined, then you were wrong in saying the polynomial could be written with $x^0$ in the final term. <rant>Quite frankly, I strongly support just defining $0^0=1$ (an oft-used definition despite what some claim). The objections I see raised to this amount to claiming a function cannot be discontinuous at a point unless it is undefined there. $0^0=1$ is overwhelmingly more useful than any other convention.</rant>